# cakephp piechart by dynamic data

Tags: php, cakephp, google-pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart in cakephp by dynamic data.I already create this but it is static. how can i make it dynamic. my code here.

```
<?php 
echo $this->GoogleChart->create ()
    ->setTitle ( 'Trips Request Graph', array ('size' => 26, 'color' => '000000' ) )
    ->setType ( 'pie', array ('3d' ) )
    ->setSize ( 1000, 300 )
    ->setMargins ( 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 )
    ->addData ( array (10,10,10) )
    ->setPieChartLabels ( array ('Riajul','Rafsan','Taukir' ) );
?>
```

I want to set data in `->addData()` and `->setPieChartLabels` section

Comment: Please Correct the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$arr = array ( 0 => "Riajul", 1 => "Rafsan", 2 => "Taukir"); // your data

$nameString = implode (", ", $arr);  // create a comma separated string

echo $this->GoogleChart->create()->setTitle ( 'Trips Request Graph', array ('size' => 26, 'color' => '000000' ) )
    ->setType ( 'pie', array ('3d' ) )
    ->setSize ( 1000, 300 )
    ->setMargins ( 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 )
    ->addData ( array (10,10,10) )
    ->setPieChartLabels ( array ($nameString) ); 
?>
```